# Rest API Reponse : Uppercase to camelcase

Tags: java, angular, rest, db2

What is the Best way to convert Uppercase values to camel case.
Lets say I have API with response {"name":"VIRAT KOHLI","teams":"RCB INDIA DELHI"}
Should it be handle  at DB query level or Java level (Business logic) or at Client-side like using Angular pipes. What is the best practices and what is best in terms of performance ?

At database I am using simple JDBC query.

Comment: Well... It depends of what you want to achieve. If you only need to display uppercase strings as camelCase strings on your app, then go for Angular/Front-end approach. However if your rest-api (server side) is public/is used by other apps, and you need to standardise your response, then you might want to pick backend approach or even database one (if you can).

Answer (score 1):

So I don't think there's a *huge difference* in performance or speed.
**However**, if you are working with a **very large amount** of data, doing the conversion at the database level could add a little bit **more time**.

It all depends on your context but you can :

- Do it by Angular using the "TitleCasePipe"(https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe#titlecasepipe)
  **or**
  avoid repetition by doing a ".map()" on the received data by putting in camelCase the concerned fields (*there are a lot of examples out there*).
- Do it on the Business layer of your Backend just making sure to do the transformation before sending the response.
- Finally do it from the database (*not recommended*) but you have to take into account that the code is always faster than a database query.